# Дико(О)браз

Tags: орфография

По логике слово должно писаться через два О - "дикоОбраз". Ведь тут два корня и соединительная - О. Но на практике пишут через одно О - "дикобраз", хоть так даже не звучит. Почему выбрасывают соединительную О?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, действительно,  этимология слова прозрачна. С течением времени произошло стяжение гласных - т.е. слияние двух рядом стоящих гласных в один.  Два гласных рядом ("зияние")
  произносить сложнее, требуются определенные  артикуляционные усилия. Это и приводит к упрощению. Другие примеры стяжения: Феодор - Фёдор, небесныих - небесных

Comment: А мне "дикоОбраз" говорить проще, чем "дикобраз")))

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых тут есть два варианта возражений сторонников формы "дикообраз".

Иногда предлагают считать правильной форму "дикообраз" как составное от "дико" и "образ". Поэтому сначала об этом.
В русском языке с незамамятных времен действует правило запрета на зияние гласных, т.е. нескольких фонетических гласных подряд, отдельные исключения сейчас не обсуждаем, у них есть объяснения.

Поэтому от "дико" и "образ" фонетически получилось бы "дико**в**образ".  
Но в "дико" О - флексия, она и не должна использоваться при образовании слова.
Такое в русском встречается: времяисчисление, времяпрепровождение: семядоля, семяножка, семяпочка (по Розенталю), хотя это слова немного другого порядка, сам принцип "сложения" без соединительной гласной понятен.

*Только не приводите в контрпример "Беларусь". Этот уродец рожден стараниями политиков и вунужденно рассматривается в русском языке как нечленимое, а не сотавное от "Бела" и "Русь".*

И собствено по идее писать "дикообраз" и членить как "дик"+о+"образ". 
Во-первых, аналогичное возражение. Такое членение дало бы либо "диковобраз" либо (менее верояно) стяжение двух О в одно. 
Во-вторых, такого стяжения и не требуется. Дикобраз - просто слово, не имеюшее соединительной гласной, членение: "дик+образ".

Такие слова в русском есть: времяисчисление, времяпрепровождение: семядоля, семяножка, семяпочка (по Розенталю). И хотя это слова совершенно иного порядка, сам принцип "бессоединительного словосложения" понятен.